# First time homebrew installation failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, homebrew, failed-installation

I've just been introduced to Ruby on Rails and am following instructions to install "homebrew" (using a Mac El Capitan 10.11.3). I tried installing Homebrew by copy pasting the line of installation code from the homebrew website but somehow got an 'failed during' message (this is the first time I tried installation).

I was clueless so I just re-entered the line of code again, here is what comes up (the second time, I get 'file exists' and the 'failed during'):

```
 ==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
remote: Counting objects: 54, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (20/20), done.
remote: Total 54 (delta 45), reused 40 (delta 33), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (54/54), done.
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master': Unable to 
create '/usr/local/Homebrew/.git/refs/remotes/origin/master.lock':
File exists.

If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
From https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
! [new branch]      master     -> origin/master  (unable to update
local ref)
Failed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master --
tags --force --depth=1
```

I am completely new to development and have no clue how to proceed. Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: Well the error tells you what to do: `If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
process is running and remove the file manually to continue`

Comment: thanks for the reply cel, i'm not quite sure what a git process is specifically, can you help me understand? i didn't have any programs running besides safari during that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete this file

`/usr/local/Homebrew/.git/refs/remotes/origin/master.lock`

try

```
rm -f /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/refs/remotes/origin/master.lock
```

and then try again

Comment: Thanks for the reply root545! I've followed you steps and this seemed to help remove 'file exists' part and the 'unable to update local ref'. Unfortunately, the installation is not going through due to the same last little part : 'failed during: git fetch ...'.

Comment: root545, i cannot thank you enough. You are a legend.  For some reason after updating git (may or may not have affected the installation), restarting the mac and then following your steps again, it magically worked! :)

Comment: glad that i could help :)